# How to make my TabLayout header be under ToolBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have the app with 5 tabs in TabLayout. I decided to initialize it in MainActivity. Each tab is a fragment and each of them has its own ToolBar, so I decided to initialize toolbars in every fragment separately. But the problem is that my toolbars now are under the TabLaout header. I want to ask how it's possible to move them down or maybe I should organize in some another way?

MainActivity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Example of fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="90"
    android:background="#20000000"
    android:visibility="gone" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="Your Wi-Fi is online">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="36dp"
      android:layout_margin="17dp"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:text="@string/pause"
      android:textColor="@color/midPurple"
      android:textSize="14sp" />

  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

TabLayout inisialization:

```
  private void initUIComponents() {
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mTabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MenuCategoryAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
      mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.homeicon);
    }
  }
```

Example of ToolBar initialization:

```
  private void initUIComponents(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mToolbarHome = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_home);
    mBtnPause = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);

    if (mToolbarHome != null) {
      ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbarHome);
    }

    mBtnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        pauseWiFi(mToolbarHome, mBtnPause);
      }
    });
  }
```

How does it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @NileshRathod Because in every tab ToolBar should be different, with different buttons and go on. So the only way to solve it, I've decided to build ToolBar in every fragment xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you set your `ViewPager`'s height to `math_parent`, and put `TabLayout` over your `ViewPager` with `80dp` of top margin to reserve space for fragments toolbar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your fragment, put fake and empty `TabLayout` under toolbar to reserve the `TabLayout`'s space and under it you can put your other views

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="90"
        android:background="#20000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="Your Wi-Fi is online">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="17dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/pause"
            android:textColor="@color/midPurple"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/fake_tabs"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <!-- Your other views -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's just create empty and (!) visible ToolBar. But that one I need to move is still on the top.

Comment: Why empty?! I create toolbar inside fragment, and you can design it in each fragment